# JavaScript program to change color using the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to create a simple program that can change an element between three different colors. However, when I set my classes, everything seems fine, but at the moment of pressing my red button nothing happens. How can I fix this issue?

I'm not quite sure how the DOM works.

```js
function cambioR() {
  let cajaCambio = document.getElementsByClassName("cajaCambio");
  document.cajaCambio.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
.Titulo {
  padding-left: 410px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.Parrafo-Explicativo {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #4158D0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black
}

.contenedor {
  float: right;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  margin-top: -140px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-left: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.botonRojo {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.botonVerde {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.botonAzul {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.cajaCambio {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-right: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="Titulo">Practica JS</h1>
<p class="Parrafo-Explicativo">Este programa constara de 3 botones los cuales podran ser presionados y causaran distintas reacciones y cosas a nuestro programa como cambiar titulos etc.</p>
<div class="contenedor">
  <button class="botonRojo" button onclick="cambioR()">Ejemplo Verde</button>
  <button class="botonVerde">Ejemplo Azul</button>
  <button class="botonAzul">Ejemplo Rojo</button>
</div>
<div class="cajaCambio"></div>
```

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a `HTMLCollection` and not a single element. Use `document.getElementsByClassName("cajaCambio")[0]` to access the first element in the collection or `document.querySelector(".cajaCambio")`. Furthermore your variable is called `cajaCambio` and not part of `document`. So remove `document.` from `document.cajaCambio`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to carefully read the documentation for the method, `getElementsByClassName` because it returns an array. Therefore your line `document.cajaCambio.style.backgroundColor = "red";` is incorrect.

At a minimum, try `cajaCambio[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";` which would set the background color on the first element in the array of elements that matched the class you were searching for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName for more information.

Comment: why are you posting two answers?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would want to learning JavaScript today.

I would use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). That way you don't have to think about an array. It gets the first item on the page with that specific class and you can start working with it as a single entity.

You could do like this in my modified example that you add a `data-color` to your buttons, add eventlisteners to them and change the color with classes. That will reduce the repetitive code you have to do. Of course that could be done with the approach you do as well, but for my taste this is the way to go.

`document.querySelector('.cajaCambio')`

```js
// we get all the buttons
const changeColorActions = document.querySelectorAll('.js-change-color')

// we loop through the buttons
changeColorActions.forEach((action) => {

  // we add eventListeners to each one of the buttons
  action.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // we get the color that is specified on data (on the button)
    const color = action.dataset.color

    // we get the target
    const target = document.querySelector('.cajaCambio')

    // we remove other color classes
    target.classList.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.includes('color--')) {
        target.classList.remove(item)
      }
    })

    // we add the new color class
    target.classList.add(`color--${color}`)
  })
})
```

```css
.Titulo {
  padding-left: 410px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.Parrafo-Explicativo {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #4158D0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(43deg, #4158D0 0%, #C850C0 46%, #FFCC70 100%);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black
}

.contenedor {
  float: right;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  margin-top: -140px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-left: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.botonRojo {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.botonVerde {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.botonAzul {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.cajaCambio {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-right: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.color--blue {
background-color: blue;
}

.color--red {
background-color: red;
}

.color--aqua {
background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="Titulo">Practica JS</h1>
<p class="Parrafo-Explicativo">Este programa constara de 3 botones los cuales podran ser presionados y causaran distintas reacciones y cosas a nuestro programa como cambiar titulos etc.</p>
<div class="contenedor">
  <button class="botonRojo js-change-color" data-color="red">Ejemplo Verde</button>
  <button class="botonVerde js-change-color" data-color="blue">Ejemplo Azul</button>
  <button class="botonAzul js-change-color" data-color="aqua">Ejemplo Rojo</button>
</div>

<div class="cajaCambio"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for an array of elements that have a specific CSS class, but then you are assuming you are getting the DOM element. Your current code would work with the line `cajaCambio[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"` instead, but a more efficient method would be to assign the HTML elements with a unique ID. Then, you can select one element by it's ID. `<button id="rojo">` would then be found with `document.getElementById('rojo')`

Comment: I did that but the button wont work idk if is the onclick honestly idk too much about javascript

Comment: why are you posting two answers?

Comment: This answer is only for supplemental information related to searching by IDs, which is not really answering the original question.

Comment: Put that as a part of your answer post.